# Why won't my controls display when added to a tab programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls

I have an application which reads from a database.  For each tuple in the database my WinForm application creates a new panel which is then populated with various information with dynamically created labels. The position is then offset and the next panel is created. I was informed that I need to now have my application support tabs. Each tab will only show so many panels. My problem occurred when I tried to add these dynamically created panels to the tab control instead of this.control. When I did so the panels and their information was no longer being drawn and I can't figure out how to make the panels display.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    panel = new Panel();
    panel.Location = position;
    panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    panel.Width = 240;
    panel.Height = 210;

    company = new Label();
    company.Location = new Point(panel.Location.X + 10, panel.Location.Y + 10);
    company.Text = tempServer.Value.companyName;
    company.Font = new Font(company.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold);

    tabs.TabPages["1"].Controls.Add(company);
            this.Controls.Add(panel);
    this.Controls.Add(tabs);
    this.Controls.SetChildIndex(tabs, this.Controls.Count);
}
```

**Update:** 
I decided to try something. I reverted all the the controls to be added by This.Controls.add(control); all the panels once again where being displayed. i then created 
Label someLabel = new Label();
someLabel.Text = "SomeText";
 i then added it to the tabs when i did that all the the panels once again disapeared

**Solution**
The problem was that I was referencing the tab pages name, when i used an index position it worked correctly and my panels are now being displayed

Comment: You never added the panel to the tabpage, just the label.  Add the label to the panel, add the panel to the tabbage.  The label's location should not use the panel's location.

Comment: it tried it and it still doesnt work

Comment: You can't get help with "it doesn't work".  Just do this in the designer first, then look at the code that the designer generated in the form's Designer.cs file.  Do the exact same thing in your code.

Comment: tabs is of type TabControl

Comment: what is the type of `tabs`?

Comment: i dont understand does each individual tab in a tab control have its own type

Comment: Check my answer if you want correct it's locations and positions but generally follow the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the dimensions of the Form are Ok and the Form has a tab control named "tabs", the following code should work.:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // create the panel
                var panel = new Panel();
                panel.Location = new Point(100, 100);
                panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                panel.Width = 240;
                panel.Height = 210;

                // create a label
                var company = new Label();
                company.Location = new Point(panel.Location.X + 10, panel.Location.Y + 10);
                company.Text = "Company";

                // add the label into panel
                panel.Controls.Add(company);

                // add the panel into the first tab page of the tab control
                tabs.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(panel);
            }
```